# Login counter set its value to 0 in database after every login

Tags: authentication, counter, login-script

i am trying to  create login counter so that any user logs on to the application have to change password on first login and moreover admin can see login counts of each and every user.

i have created a private sub to count no of login. It runs nicely for 0 no of logins but when some user has logged on too many time in the application it sets the login counter value to 0 in database.

```
Private Sub countLogin()
    Dim comm As OleDbCommand
    Dim commStr As String = "SELECT Login_Counter FROM Login_Table Where User_Name = '" _
    & txtUsername.Text & "'"
    Dim RD As OleDbDataReader
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim CLcomm As OleDbCommand
    Dim CLcommStr As String = "UPDATE Login_Table SET [Login_Counter] = " & j & " WHERE User_Name = '" & txtUsername.Text & "'"

    conn = New OleDbConnection(connStr)
    conn.Open()

    comm = New OleDbCommand(commStr, conn)
    RD = comm.ExecuteReader

    While RD.Read

        i = RD.GetInt32(0)

    End While

    If i = 0 Then
        Dim nf As New ChangePassword
        nf.ShowDialog(Me)
    End If

    j = i + 1
    MsgBox(j)
    CLcomm = New OleDbCommand(CLcommStr, conn)
    CLcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Secondly, I suspect you're using an integer datatype too small to count the number of logins. Is it rolling over after 127, 255, 32767 or 65535 logins?

Comment: So, what should i use in lieu of integer ? See, i am a newbie in this field and trying to learn something from experienced guys like you.

Comment: Without knowing what the backing database is I couldn't say with certainty, but if integer in this case is 32-bit or higher it will be fine.

Comment: its MS Access Database and its 32 bit integer

Comment: So unless people are going to log in more than 2.1 billion times, it should be fine as-is.

Answer (score 1):

When you set CLcommStr, j hasen't been set to a value yet, so it is zero.

Try setting CLcommStr after you've set j to the new value.

Comment: but j gets value at j = i + 1 then it goes to database

Comment: At that point you've already set CLcommStr to the SQL you want executed. When you set CLcommStr j was 0, so CLcommStr contains SQL that says "UPDATE Login_Table SET [Login_Counter] = 0 WHERE User_Name ...". You need to set CLcommStr after you've calculated the new value. Try adding "MsgBox(CLcommStr)" where you also display the value of j to see that it's zero.